# Smarty html_options value attribute not working

Tags: php, templates, smarty, html-select

I am trying to display an dropdown list with smarty html_options. It shows the dropdown nicely but output values as 0,1,2,3,4,5.

But I want values to be 100,150,200,250,300,350.

======PHP =========

```
$choice_set=array("A","B","C","D","E","F");
$choice_values=array(100,150,200,250,300,350);
$choice=250;
```

=====SMARTY=========

```
<select name="location">
{html_options values=$choice_values options=$choice_set selected=$choice}
</select>
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their [docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.options.tpl), it looks like you forgot to stick on the size bit for the select. Also, it says the `options` needs to be `output` (which seems like a really poor name to me). Like this:

```
<select name="location" size="{$choice_values|@count}">
    {html_options values=$choice_values output=$choice_set selected=$choice}
</select>
```

**Update:** Based on Gerald's excellent point in the comments.

You could use the `options` template value if you instead defined an associative array instead of separate arrays. So this would also work:

======PHP =========

```
$choices = array(100 => "A, 150 => "B", 200 => "C", 250 => "D", 300 => "E", 350 => "F");
$choice=250;
```

=====SMARTY=========

```
<select name="location">
    {html_options options=$choices selected=$choice}
</select>
```

Also, I frequently forgot to `$smarty->assign` my variables, especially when I was prototyping or changing something. You're probably smarter than me, in that regard, but it's worth double checking.

Sorry for my oversight, it's been a while since I used smarty.

Comment: thanx for your response.

There the size means how many rows should be displayed on the display area. It does not help for my issue.

Comment: the `options=` parameter is supposed to be an associative array, like `array(100=>'A', 150=>'B',...)`. If you want to use two separate arrays you have to use the parameters `values=`and `output=`, NOT `options=`

Comment: Oops, @GeraldSchneider is exactly correct. I should have put that in my answer. Updating it now :-)

Comment: PatrickM, GeraldSchneider Thank you very much for both of your effort. You are right it needs to be a two dimensional array.